# How to call an Active Model Serializer inline as an option to a hash assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-model-serializers

I am sure this might be a stretch but I'm very impressed with the flexibility that Active Model Serializers provide. I'd like to something like:

```
 def by_location_and_bin_number
    @items=MenuItem.where('bin_number=? and location_id=?', params[:bin_number], params[:location_id]).is_valid
    r={}
    r[:status]="success"
    r[:count] = @tems.count
    r[:menu_items] = @items, serializer: ItemMicroSerializer # <- not working
    render json: r.to_json
  end
```

but this doesn't work. How can I get this to work (or similar syntax)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the requirement and what didn't work?

Comment: here's the error `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    r[:menu_items] = @items, serializer: ItemMicroSerializer`

Comment: Can you please try `r[:menu_items] = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@items, each_serializer: ItemMicroSerializer).to_json`. I haven't worked with serializers gem yet so I am not sure.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it does work = been one of those days :-( Thx so much for help

Comment: If it worked then should I write it up in answer?

Comment: yep - just I found you need to take the .to_json off when rendering as part of a hash as I have here - because we call .to_json on it later and causes a second set of quotes so `r[:menu_items] = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@items, each_serializer: ItemMicroSerializer)` ; thx again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to serialize the array `@items`, you can use the independent method as

```
r[:menu_items] = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@items, each_serializer: ItemMicroSerializer)
```

It will serialize the provided array of objects by serializing each object using ItemMicroSerializer.